# Issue with the window focus in WinRT

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, desktop-application

I've got an issue with the focus management in WinRT. The issue is specific for the application startup. Let me share the example of it:
If during the startup I change the focus (for instance I can start selecting some text in a browser), the runtime will decide that it doesn't need to show the application. The application is being started in a 'hidden mode'. It means that I do not see the UI, but I still can find it in process explorer.

So what I need here is to make the application be active in all possible cases. I tried to use several native functions such as ShowWindow, SetActiveWindow, SetForegroundWindow, but without any success.

I also noticed that any WinRT app is being started under WWAHOST.exe and mainwindowhandle is 0. The app shows up if I use 'Switch to' option in Process Explorer context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinRT applications are sandboxed and have very little control on the way the OS handles them, and almost no way to affect the behavior of other applications running on the same host. What I would suggest then is for you to design your application in such a way that it shows some UI as early as possible, then asynchronously you can load any other resources that your application may need.